# I am using mass update in netsuite to insert the remark custom field of all sales order(350) ,i got error message?

Tags: netsuite

I am using mass update in netsuite to insert the remark custom field  of all sales order(350) ,when 45 sales order are completed it give me following error message?

[Error after 45 recorde updated using nlapiUpdateRecord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz4AO.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Alternate Solution:

1.    Create a Service Item for Sale item via Lists> Accounting > Items > New
2.    Tag it to the sales account that the user normally use for the posting discount items
3.    Use the new item in sales transactions after the line item that the user needs to apply the discount to
4.    Make sure that the Amount column shows a negative value for this item

GL Impact of the transaction should now show a Debit to the sales discount account.
User has the option of tagging a Rev. Rec. Template to this “discount” item and recognizing it at the same time as the other items in the transaction via Transactions > Financial > Create Revenue Recognition Journal Entries
```

**From: (Unable to add posting discount in sales transactions with Revenue Recognition Templates / Schedules)**

Suite Answers #39829 (Requires Netsuite login) may yield some helpful information regarding this issue that you're having. It may also be helpful to see the difference between a record that was completed successfully and one that wasn't, as the error message gives you some investigation info.